# CU6 to CU 11 upgrade on SQL 2019 makes queries towards Tabular functions very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

After upgrading from SQL server 2019 CU6 to CU11:
below query marked with --Slow running query
is slow suddenly.
CD_TF() contains OUTER APPLY to another TF.

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#BrowseList1') IS NOT NULL)
DROP TABLE #BrowseList1
  CREATE TABLE #BrowseList1
  ( 
     RowNumber        dbo.ecm_RowNumber_DT IDENTITY(1,1)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,OrderId        dbo.ecm_OrderId_DT 
    ,OrderGroupId     dbo.ecm_OrderGroupId_DT
    ,InterfaceId      dbo.ecm_InterfaceId_DT              
  );
  
  INSERT INTO #BrowseList1(OrderId,OrderGroupId,InterfaceId)
SELECT OrderId,OrderGroupId,InterfaceId FROM AB_TF()
WHERE ( HolderId = N'1' ) ORDER BY OrderGroupId ASC;

--Slow running query 
SELECT o.*
FROM CD_TF() AS o 
INNER JOIN 
#BrowseList1 AS browser ON (o.OrderId = browser.OrderId AND o.OrderGroupId = browser.OrderGroupId AND o.InterfaceId = browser.InterfaceId)
```

Comment: CU11 disabled inlining for certain types of functions due to bugs, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/06/sit-down-we-need-to-talk-about-your-scalar-functions/. We need to see the function's code to know for sure

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the inlining performance penalty is only for scalar user defined functions not table valued functions. Either way we still need to see the definition of the function!